# Batch file to "echo" files older than 7 days

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have tried the following command:

```
forfiles /P "C:\test\" /S /M *.* /D -7 /C "cmd /c echo @path"
```

but it returns an error:
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sBLf.jpg)

I'm not sure what's wrong, the syntax should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the last backslash in your search path : "c:\test" instead of "c:\test\"
So it should be :

```
forfiles /P "C:\test" /S /M *.* /D 7 /C "cmd /c echo @path"
```

Comment: Question from your screenshot : How are you executing this command line ? Have your tried with an opened console ?

Comment: and yes, I have tried with an opened command line, still the same

Comment: I have reproduced your problem, and edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: It is ok now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`/D 7` is "seven days in the future". Unlikely you have such files (except you own one of those awesome time travel machines).

```
forfiles /P "C:\test\" /S /M *.* /D -7 /C "cmd /c echo @path"
```

Comment: run with `echo on` and copy paste the output into your question.